# HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden error message when using Wikipedia API

Tags: php, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to use an API to search wikipedia for a word that the user who fills out my form typed in. So, if they typed "cat" into the form, the API would then search wikipedia for entries containing the word "cat". I got it to work, but now I"m getting this message:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=parrott): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in /var/www/html/flam1-api.php on line 22
```

I read about perhaps needing a user-agent, but I'm not sure what exactly to do. Here's my code:

```php
    echo "<h1>Which LOLcat are you? Results!</h1>";
    $visit_id = $_COOKIE['visit_id'];
    $all_my_variables = json_decode(file_get_contents("/var/www/html/data/$visit_id.json"));
    //var_dump($all_my_variables);
    $animal = $all_my_variables ->favoriteanimal;
    echo "When searching wikipedia entries on your favorite animal, which is a $animal, we got the results:<br>";
     $website = file_get_contents('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search='.urlencode($animal).'');

        echo $website[0];
```

I definitely appreciate any help on this!

Comment: See the [WikiMedia User-Agent policy](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy).

Answer (score 3):

You need to set a user agent (perhaps by using the `curl` extension instead of `file_get_contents`). The default user agent used by `file_get_contents` is explicitly blocked, as it's often associated with abusive behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Some sites blocks using file_get_contents. 
I don't have a chnace to test now, but try using this function isntead of file_get_contents.

```
function get_url_contents($url){
        $crl = curl_init();
        $timeout = 5;
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        $ret = curl_exec($crl);
        curl_close($crl);
        return $ret;
}
```

Comment: The problem is the User Agent. I would think the default User Agent of curl is blocked too, so you have to set it explicitly.